# How do I get the SUM of those three COUNTS()?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Here's my query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '1') AS `count1`,
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1') AS `count2`,
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table3` WHERE `id` = '1') AS `count3`
```

How can I get the sum of `count1, count2, count3`?

Is there any way I can do it **in the query** above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Simply add the values together:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '1') +
       (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1') +
       (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table3` WHERE `id` = '1') AS `sum` ...
```

Comment: Uh, nice. Thanks a lot, Andrew!